# if li have no left child then its append on div tag when click on it

Tags: javascript

this is my xml file:-

```
<root>
  <child_1 entity_id = "1" value="Game" parent_id="0">
    <child_2 entity_id="2" value="Activities" parent_id="1">
      <child_3 entity_id="3" value="Physical1" parent_id="2">
        <child_6 entity_id="6" value="Cricket" parent_id="3">
          <child_7 entity_id="7" value="One Day" parent_id="6"/>
        </child_6>
      </child_3>
      <child_4 entity_id="4" value="Test1" parent_id="1">
        <child_8 entity_id="8" value="Test At Abc" parent_id="4"/>
      </child_4>
      <child_5 entity_id="5" value="Test2" parent_id="1">
        <child_9 entity_id="9" value="Test At Xyz" parent_id="5"/>
      </child_5>
    </child_2>
</child_1>
</root>
```

this is my xslt to find All Activities from the xml file and set there attribute value into `ul li` 
now i want to set on them if leaf `li` then click on it and  it append in my `<div id="result"></div>`

i am try this.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="a.css"></link>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script>
        var xml = loadXMLDoc("abc.xml");
        var xsl = loadXMLDoc("a.xsl");



        function loadXMLDocOther(location) {
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.open("GET", location, false);
            xhttp.send("");
            return xhttp.responseXML;
        }

        function loadXMLDoc(dname) {
            if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                return loadXMLDocActiveX(dname);
            }
            else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                return loadXMLDocOther(dname);
            }
        }        
        function transformOther(xml, xsl, target, selected) {
            var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
            xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);

            if (selected) {
                xsltProcessor.setParameter(null, "selected", selected);
            }

            var resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
            target.innerHTML = "";
            target.appendChild(resultDocument);
        }

        function displayResult() {
            var targetElement = document.getElementById("load");

            // code for IE
            if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                transformActiveX(xml, xsl, targetElement);
            }
            // code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
            else if (document.implementation && 
                     document.implementation.createDocument) {
                transformOther(xml, xsl, targetElement);
            }
        }
           $('li:not(:has(*))').click(function(){
           $('#result').text($(this).text());
           });
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="displayResult()">
    <div id="load">
    </div>
    <div id="result">result</div>
</body>
```

i am try above all code but its not work.
help me out with this.
thanks.